# How cna I a add comma between words in a td if there is more than one word

Tags: javascript

Long backstory on this, and this seems to be the simplest solution. I have a table that will populate with user id's from a database. I need to figure out a way to add a comma between id's if there is more than one. The td id is `username`.

I'm not sure where to really start. I would need to index it and see if the html is > 1. And if so, add a comma between each word. Please help. This is a p.o.c forum and it doesn't suit me to add/use jQuery, so I need to do it in vanilla JavaScript.

Here is the code that pulls it from the database:

```
if ($this->post['post_thanks_amount'] > 0 && $this->thread['isdeleted'] == 0)
{
    $this->post['post_thanks_bit'] = fetch_thanks_bit($this->thread['forumid'], $thanks);
    $this->post['post_thanks_user'] = $post_thanks_user;
    $this->post['post_thanks_amount_formatted'] = vb_number_format($this->post['post_thanks_amount']);
    $post_thanks_box = fetch_post_thanks_template($this->post);
}
```

And the output with one user is this:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td style="background:#E8E8E8;" colspan="2" class="alt1">
        <div>
            <a rel="nofollow" href="member.php?u=20420">ninja1</a>
            <a rel="nofollow" href="member.php?u=26154">testuser</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

so after each `<a...>` if there is more than one, add a comma.

Comment: Can you show us your current table and what should it like after the processing ?

Comment: What do you mean? You want commas between the actual td contents? How will you know if you have more than one? What are you using to read from the database?

Comment: Your question is quite vague. You say the id's come from the database, but what 'format' is the data returned? How are your is your datastucture for those id's in js? In an array, an object, json, ? All of these formats would have different solutions.

Comment: Apologies all, pls see edited question.thx

Comment: A POC *is* a reason to use a library like jQuery. What else is it a POC for?

Comment: @edwin, man I know but it's not applicable here, trust me.

Comment: How are the links generated on the server side? Can't you add commas in PHP?

Comment: @Felix King - I think I could in the top block of code above, how would I do it? would I write a second if statement? that changes the "if ($this->post['post_thanks_amount'] > 0 && $this->thread['isdeleted'] == 0)" to a "if ($this->post...>1"?

Comment: Well, I don't know what part of your code exactly produce the links... is it `$this->post['post_thanks_user'] = $post_thanks_user;`? Or are you looping somewhere and adding the names of the users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If ids is an array, then just use `join`:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
val = ids.join(', ');
// val is now "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `[1].join(", ")` outputs `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` automatically puts comma between words, if that's what you're looking for.

```
var words = 'a b c d';
document.write(words.split(' '));
```

Comment: It's best to be explicit: `"a b c d".split(" ").join(", ");`

Comment: This is a bit misleading. `split` does not add commas. It returns an array and an array's defaults string representation is a comma separated list of its values.